# Heart of the swarm campaign view shows 87% but all rewards are "earned"

Tags: starcraft-2

When I click my profile then achievements then "swarm campaign" it shows me I've gotten 170/170 achievements, however when I select the "campagin" view, It says I've only completed 87% of the game. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to obtain 100% you will need to complete all the sub and mastery achievements as well. If you click into each of the missions, you will need to complete the achievements there.

For example this is the Kaldir missions:
[image: Kaldir Missions]

You need to get all of the of them to get 100% complete for the campaign.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit silly that the "mastery" achievements are so hidden. That's what was missing for me.